# NitroShare without system tray icon

Tags: release-juno

This starts, but there is no icon in the system tray (or no system tray), so it isn't usable. There are threads about this in earlier eOS versions.

Answer (score 1):

About system tray icons. Juno dropped the support of the old ayatana

While the software devs implement the new way you can have them back by...

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yunnxx/elementary
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install indicator-application wingpanel-indicator-ayatana
```

then you need to edit a file (i used nano, use any editor you want - avoiding a holy war)

```
$ sudo nano /etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-application.desktop
```

find the line

```
OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME;
```

and add Pantheon

```
OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME;Pantheon;
```

that's it, just restart X and you will have the old notification area icons

Comment: then accept the answer

Comment: Manners maketh man :)

Comment: don't know what you mean, just wanna say that if you don't accept it as an answer (and it is an answer) it will be bumped ad infinitum by the system and also we can't use it as answer for duplicate questions like your becaus this isn't the first time I answer the same thing but because people don't mark it I cant flag it as duplicate... so manner matter? manners depend where you are, and here if you get a working answer you mark it as accepted.